# Command-line 'msiexec /norestart /fepmcs /qn' still reboots the PC

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5, wix3.6

I am developing an installer for our product using [WiX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX). One of the services that my installer installs requires a reboot.

During UI installation, it asks the user, and if the user says "No", a reboot will not happen. However, using silent installation, even though I specify the `/norestart` option, it still reboots the machine.

Here are logs of the case without silent installation where, if the user selects "No", it doesn't restart:

```
MSI (s) (F0:58) [04:42:00:795]: Windows Installer reconfigured the product. Product Name: MyProduct. Product Version: 1.0.0.0. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: MyOrg. Reconfiguration success or error status: 0.

MSI (s) (F0:58) [04:42:00:795]: Value of RebootAction property is 
MSI (s) (F0:58) [04:42:00:795]: Windows Installer requires a system restart. Product Name: MyProduct. Product Version: 1.0.0.0. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: MyOrg. **Type of System Restart: 2. Reason for Restart: 1.**

MSI (s) (F0:58) [04:42:00:796]: Product: MyProduct. Restart required. The installation or update for the product required a restart for all changes to take effect.  The restart was deferred to a later time.
```

Here are the logs where, even though the `/norestart` option is provided, a reboot happens:

```
MSI (s) (50:78) [04:37:06:985]: Windows Installer reconfigured the product. Product Name: MyProduct. Product Version: 1.0.0.0. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: MyOrg. Reconfiguration success or error status: 0.

MSI (s) (50:78) [04:37:06:985]: Value of RebootAction property is 
MSI (s) (50:78) [04:37:06:985]: Windows Installer requires a system restart. Product Name: MyProduct. Product Version: 1.0.0.0. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: MyOrg. **Type of System Restart: 1. Reason for Restart: 1**.
```

Comparing the both log files, I noticed the following difference:

Success Case:
**Type of System Restart: 2. Reason for Restart: 1.**

Failure case:
**Type of System Restart: 1. Reason for Restart: 1**

Do I need to add any properties in WiX code to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding REBOOT=ReallySuppress to your command line.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour was as expected.

I was missing one point. This was happening during repair. I forgot that repair ignores any command-line parameters passed.